# Openstack API not providing precise data

Tags: rest, openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-api

I am using Openstack - Stein in CentOS 7.9

I was using python to collect data about the openstack nova performance, like server names and id in the openstack project, i have 3 instance(server) created, i can see all three instance in openstack cli, but when i connect to api mentioned in openstack, it provides no data or less data.

I refereed openstack documentation [here](https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/compute/?expanded=#servers-topology-servers-topology)

```
[root@centos-vm1 kavin(keystone_admin)]# openstack server list
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+--------+----------------------------------------+-------+----------+
| ID                                   | Name            | Status | Networks                               | Image | Flavor   |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+--------+----------------------------------------+-------+----------+
| 08cf6226-0303-4b4c-ba53-10af79b81dae | test_instance_3 | ACTIVE | test_networ_3=10.150.0.8               |       | m1.tiny  |
| 9986f205-82b3-4cbb-bcdc-fb32eab97c83 | test_instance_1 | ACTIVE | test_networ_2=10.100.0.5, x.x.x.x      |       | m1.small |
| d1c0f520-8540-432c-8fe1-554390fd79bf | test_instance_2 | ACTIVE | test_networ_1=10.50.0.8                |       | m1.small |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+--------+----------------------------------------+-------+----------+
```

My python code:

```
import requests,json
from six.moves.urllib.parse import urljoin

identity = {
    "methods": ["password"],
    "password": {
    "user": {
          "name": "admin",
          "domain": { "id": "default" },
          "password": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    }
}

OS_AUTH_URL = 'http://x.x.x.x:5000/v3'
data = {'auth': {'identity': identity}}
HEADERS = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'scope': 'unscoped'}

r = requests.post(
 OS_AUTH_URL+'/auth/tokens',
  headers = HEADERS,
  json    = data,     
  verify  = False
 )
auth_token = r.headers['X-Subject-Token']  # i got auth token

# server list
NOVA_URL="http://x.x.x.x:8774/v2.1"
HEADERS = {"X-Auth-Token" : str(auth_token)}
r = requests.get(
    NOVA_URL+'/servers',
    headers = HEADERS,
 )
r.raise_for_status()
print(r.json())
```

Output :

```
{'servers': []}
```

help me, collect accurate data using api calls, thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to api-ref **[List Servers](https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/compute/?expanded=list-servers-detail#list-servers)** doc, maybe you should add the *[project scope](https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/pike/api_curl_examples.html#project-scoped)* in the request.

> By default the servers are filtered using the project ID associated with the authenticated request.

In my opinion, you could use **[openstacksdk](https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/latest/)** to execute the operation, simply with the *[Connection](https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/latest/user/connection.html)* object and *[list_servers](https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/latest/user/connection.html#openstack.connection.Connection.list_servers)* method.

```
import openstack
conn = openstack.connect(
    region_name='example-region',
    auth_url='http://x.x.x.x:5000/v3/',
    username='amazing-user',
    password='super-secret-password',
    project_id='33...b5',
    domain_id='05...03'
)
servers = conn.list_servers()
```